# How to binding a ComboBox SelectedValue property to TextBox Text property inside ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox, textbox

I have a ComboBox and TextBox inside a ListView, How I could binding the SelectedValue to Text, My code:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="130">
     <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Caracteristica" />
         <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCaracteristica" Width="100" />
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn Width="100">
         <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Tipo" />
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                      <TextBox x:Name="txtTipoValor" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=cmbCaracteristica, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                     </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
```

This not working. 
PD: The ItemSource of ComboBox load in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a property of the type `T` in your `IEnumerable<T>` `ItemsSource`, and then bind the `TextBox` to the same source property:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="130">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Caracteristica" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCaracteristica" Width="100"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Width="100">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Tipo" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtTipoValor"
                         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Make sure that the type `T` implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

You cannot bind an element in one `CellTemplate` to an element in another `CellTemplate` using `ElementName`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **DisplayMemberPath** property? Works for me in the same situation.

```
  <ListView DisplayMemberPath="MainList" </ListView>
```

Works for selected item from MainList, you can do the same for textbox.